# Regular expression to replace brackets that embrace whole entry

Tags: python, regex, notepad++

I have a tab-delimited txt file.

```
1    (hi7 there)    my
2    (hi7)there    he3
```

I want to remove brackets only when that bracket embraces the whole entry(I am not sure if the word entry is the right word to describe it, anyhow)

So the output should be

```
1    hi7 there    my
2    (hi7)there    he3
```

I know I can easily find how to remove all brackets. But I couldn't find how to remove brackets only when they embrace the whole entry.

Can I do it simply by using notepad++ or python, whichever is faster?

Comment: Are they really tabs characters, or just multiple spaces?

Comment: Performance doesn't really matter, does it? Anyways, since you didn't show your attempts, I will give you a hint: use a positive lookahead to check if there is a white-space ahead `(?=\s)`.

Comment: @Robin They are divided by tabs. I don't know how to put tabs in stackoverflow post. But they are indeed divided by tabs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This expr seems to handle all possibilities correctly:

```
(?m)     # multiline mode
(^|\t)   # start of line of field 
\(       # (
   ([^\t]+?) # anything but a tab
\)       # )
(?=      # followed by...
   $|\t  # end of line or field
)
```

replace with `\1\2`.

Example:

```
import re

rx = r'(?m)(^|\t)\(([^\t]+?)\)(?=$|\t)'

txt = """
1   (hi7 (the)re)   (my)
2   (hi7)there  he3
(22)    (hi7)there  he3
(22)    (hi7there)  (he3)
"""

print re.sub(rx, r'\1\2', txt)
```

Result:

```
1   hi7 (the)re my
2   (hi7)there  he3
22  (hi7)there  he3
22  hi7there    he3
```

Comment: How can I use this in notepad++ so that I can test it? If it has to be done by python, how can I designate input and output file names?

Comment: @user2604484: in np++ try removing the `(?m)` bit, IIRC it does that by default.

Comment: It works great! I am confused because it works perfectly if I click 'replaceall' but it successfully replaces in the 3rd column if I repeatedly click 'replace'. Anyhow, this isn't an important issue. Then what should I do if the bracket in question is "" or {} rather than ()?  Will this be correct?:   (?m)(^|\t)\"([^\t]+?)\"(?=$|\t)

Comment: @user2604484: yes, that should be fine.

Comment: @georg great work . really got intrest on learning regex..here is the link for who want to learn regex .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16461680/regex-best-way-to-learn-it

Comment: @georg I chose your answer! Thank you.

Comment: @georg What if the input is not written in python code directly but the input is tab-delimited txt titled input.txt, and the output should be rewritten over the origianl file (rather than merely being printed) ? How should I change the code?

Answer (score 2):

i think this should work

```
f = open("file.txt")
for line in f:
 l = line.strip().split("    ")
 for word in l:
  if word[0] == "(" and word[-1] == ")":
   print (word[1:len(word)-1]),
  else:
   print (word),
 print
```

for overwrite

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.FileInput("file.txt", inplace=1):
    l = line.strip().split("    ")
    s = ""
    for sent in l:
        if sent[0] == "(" and sent[-1] == ")":
            s += sent[1:len(sent) - 1] + "    "
        else:
            s += sent + "    "
    print s[:-1]
```

Comment: @Vijay_Kumar Does this work? I tested but nothing changes in the file.

Comment: it doesnt change the file , it prints what you ask, 
if you want to change in file the open file with read/write permision
and do what you want.

Comment: Hi Vijay, how can I overwrite the result to the original file file.txt ?

Comment: hi, i added some code for overwrite result to original file

Comment: Thank you for continued help. But the code simply erased everything in the input file. The input file is tab-delimited txt. And  the input file often has non-English, although my test input didn't have non-English, and still the code erased just everything..

Comment: I tested.. but now this code simply make sure the end of every row is \s\s\s\r\n ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tab character `\t` in python regexp expression, so you can match like this :

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match('^\([^\t]+\)\t.*$', '(hi7 there)\tmy')
>>> <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x02573950>
>>> re.match('^\([^\t]+\)\t.*$', '(hi7)there\tmy')
>>>
```

Once you know how to match your string, it is easy to remove bracket only if the line match.

Comment: Be careful, this will also match `hi(there)`.

Comment: No, because you have the `^` matching the beginning of the line so the left bracket should be the first character. On my computer (python v2.7), the regexp does not match `hi(there)`.

Comment: Oops you're right, my bad. But how will it match `1 \t (hi7 there) \t my` then? (spaces added for readability)

Answer (score 0):

If they are really *tab* delimited, you can replace

```
\t\(([^\t]*)\)\t

\t           # a tab
\(           # an opening parenthesis
(            # open the capturing group
    [^\t]*   # anything but a tab
)
\)
\t
```

with

```
\t\1\t
```

The idea is to capture the text inside the relevant brackets, and to use it in the replacement with the backreference `\1`.

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/dP8yB3)

Comment: This won't work if the `(...)` column is at the beginning of the end of the line. Let me know if this is an issue, the fix is easy but renders the regex less readable.

Comment: What do you mean by "at the beginning of the end of the line"?

Comment: @user2604484: I mean in `1 \t hi7 there \t (my)` (spaces added for readability), the current regex won't replace `(my)` with `my`: it won't work on the first or last column. If you want it, you need to use @georg's solution (same idea extended)